# Smallest battery that can run the raspberry pi zero w for a short amount of time

Tags: battery, pi-zero-w

I have a raspberry pi zero w. What is the smallest (in terms of weight) that can run the pi? I am not concerned about how long it runs for; 5 mins would be adequate. What about with a camera attached?

I know that 4 AA batteries can run it for quite a few hours, but they weigh about 100g in total. Can I sacrifice run time for weight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best chance of success is to find a small [LIPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery).  They are typically used for powering radio controlled aircraft such as quadcopters.

As long as you feed more than 3.3V into the 5V pin a LIPO of large enough capacity will provide the current needed to power the Pi.

Some Pi's have proection mechanisms which kick in at 6V, so I suggest any LIPO you use should be configured to provide less than 6V.

Comment: Yes, good idea. I could probably source one from an old phone.

Comment: @Josiki Will you also carry your old phone around to charge it?

Comment: Phone batteries are unlikely to be LIPOs, probably standard Lithium cells.  In either case as [Dmitry Grigoryev](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33476/dmitry-grigoryev) suggests charging Lithium (including LIPO) batteries is not trivial.  You need special chargers.

Comment: I haven't thought that far ahead to be honest. Charging it via my phone is a definite option. Although if that doesn't work, then maybe I should go for a different approach.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer, because my main concern was the weight. After getting a battery from an old phone (samsung s3) and checking that it powered the pi, I weighed it an it was around 20g, which is a lot lighter than the other options that were suggested.

Answer (score 0):

two 3v [cr2032](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/CR_2032) button cells (190-225mah) should do the trick, considering that it uses [at most 230ma on peak load](http://raspi.tv/2017/how-much-power-does-pi-zero-w-use). So half an hour should be easily achievable. Do not forget to use a voltage regulator, as the pi does not like 6v. not sure about the power usage of a camera

Comment: In fact the Pi itself will run quite happily on 6V, although HDMI and any USB devices or attached peripherals may not.

Comment: @Milliways Does the Pi Zero even use 5V? I would think that as long as the voltage regulator supports it then it would be fine. Do we know the tolerance on the 3V3 pin to just connect 2 CR2032 in parallel?

Comment: -1. A single CR2032 only provides 15 mA, you'll need 30 of them to run an RPi Zero.

Comment: @lights0123 You should not ask questions in Comments, but the Foundation warns "Under no circumstances should a power source be connected to the 3.3V pins."

Comment: i tried putting two into it (via a micro usb cable that I had stripped apart), but it didn't seem like enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the CR2032 button cells don't provide enough current, you could try 4 AAA batteries instead of AA batteries. That should reduce the weight some.

Comment: Good idea! I will give it a try later :)

Comment: It works! But a phone battery is quite a bit lighter.

Answer (score 0):

There are boost converters which can provide 5V 300 mA off a single AA battery ([example](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/5-pcs-DC-DC-Converter-Step-Up-Boost-Module-0-9-5V-T0-5V-600MA-USB/1879190967.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10068_10084_10083_10305_10080_10304_10082_10306_10081_10177_10110_10136_10137_519_10111_10302_10060_10112_10155_10113_10114_437_10154_10056_10055_10054_10182_10059_303_10184_100031_10099_10078_10079_10103_10073_10102_10052_10053_10142_10107_142_10050_10051-10051,searchweb201603_16,ppcSwitch_2&btsid=70fd329f-7288-4f9d-9f91-446db517041d&algo_expid=0ece660f-650c-472a-a197-ebb5a1808f48-6&algo_pvid=0ece660f-650c-472a-a197-ebb5a1808f48)). Of course, the battery won't last long, but it seems that's OK for you.

Comment: That is cool! Although I don't know that it will give enough amps, I think the pi needs about 1A? Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: Depends on how you use it. If you plan to have Wifi and external devices connected, you may actually want to keep you 4 AA batteries.

Comment: Yeah, I plan to use the wifi and (possibly) have a camera connected as well. So perhaps this is not the approach for me. I don't really want to buy something just to experiment with it.